# Create and Read password protected ZIP using streams.(Not physical File)

Tags: zip4j

I need to implement a solution that creates password protected ZIP streams  and save to 
database as a

blob. Also need to read the password protected content from the database read as the stream. This

should not create a physical File.  Standard JAVA SDK does not support creating and reading  password

protected ZIP. I tried with different  solutions all most the available solution creating a physical file.

I found examples with writing/Reading password protected ZIP with ZIP4J

[How to password protect a zipped Excel file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800583/how-to-password-protect-a-zipped-excel-file-in-java)

Is it possible to create and read password protected ZIPs with ZIP4j library without creating physical files. ?

Applying a patch to the other available source seems difficult to cater my requirement.

[Write a password protected Zip file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java)

Comment: I think most of the pieces you need are in java.util.zip.

Comment: Nope. java.util.zip cannot password protect a zip

Comment: But you can do the encryption/decryption separately.

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is protecting the BLOB data in database, why don't you just use `javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream/javax.crypto.CipherInputStream`?

Reading zip content from BLOB and convert it to stream using ZIP4J is quite complicate, you have to work on file header first...(check the source code of `net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine` class)

Writing zip content into memory is easier, here is a example code:

```
ZipParameters zipParam = new ZipParameters();
zipParam.setSourceExternalStream(true);
//set parameter for encryption... 
zipParam.setEncryptFiles(true);
zipParam.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
zipParam.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
zipParam.setPassword("test123");

ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream(256);
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(bo, new ZipModel());

String[] filenames = new String[]{"1.txt"};
for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    zipParam.setFileNameInZip(filenames[0]);
    zout.putNextEntry(null, zipParam);
    zout.write(filenames[0].getBytes());//data waiting for compressed...
    zout.closeEntry();
}
zout.finish();
zout.close();

bo.toByteArray();//compressed data of zip file
```

Comment: what zip4j versoin is this?

Comment: Sample code in my answer is written with zip4j v1.3.2
It may need some change for version 2.x